# No matching distribution found for python-colorspace

Tags: python, pip, colors

I'm trying to install colourspace for python as it looks very useful for me. But am running into difficulty. Usually I'd use

```
py -3 -m pip install python-colorspace
```

but that results in:

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python-colorspace (from versions: none)

ERROR: No matching distribution found for python-colorspace

Using

py -3 -m pip install https://github.com/retostauffer/python-colorspace

brings up the message

```
Collecting https://github.com/retostauffer/python-colorspace
Downloading https://github.com/retostauffer/python-colorspace
\ 240 kB 3.3 MB/s
ERROR: Cannot unpack file C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-unpack-k1x8gn56\python- 
colorspace (downloaded from C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-r
eq-build-7ftvh7h6, content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8); cannot detect archive format
ERROR: Cannot determine archive format of C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-req-build- 
7ftvh7h6
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score -1):

As of now, `python-colorspace` package is not yet available on PyPi. According to the [Package Installation Page](https://retostauffer.github.io/python-colorspace/articles/installation.html), you can install it in 3 ways: through pip, cloning the git repository or using a virtual environment. Please note that a few requirements are needed to be able to use the package and all its features.

- Python 3.10+
- numpy
- matplotlib
- imageio (optional).

You can visit https://retostauffer.github.io/python-colorspace/articles/installation.html for more details on installation and choose your preferred method.